# Can I bill in-app purchases for user-generated offers in iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile, payment, in-app-purchase

I'm building kind of a mobile marketplace on which users can offer and buy services that are only valid for a short time (for example, 5 hours).

Is there a possibility to implement a in-app payment method (in iOS/Android) for that? The problem is that in "normal" in-app purchases you have specific, pre-defined goods or services that are bought in the app. In my marketplace, user can offer lots of different services themselves (various products, prices, etc.) so specific products wouldn't help.

Thanks in advance and kind regards,

Clemens

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for the iPhone

And as you have figured out already, it is not possible. You have to create all your in-app-purchase products in iTunes Connect, and they all have to be reviewed by apple.

And if you mean physical goods when you say "various products" then it isn't allowed anyway.
IAP is only allowed for stuff that is used inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about the iOS app store, from what I understand the Android marker is basically the wild west.

The obvious solution is to sell people "tokens" of some sort in the app, then let them trade those tokens to other users for their products/goods/services. Then you need a way to redeem people's tokens for cash, presumably keeping a modest cut "for the house". I don't see anything in the App Store TOS that would outlaw that.